# Wordpress Setting page can not be saved by html radio

Tags: php, theme-options, options

I have this php Code to make a option page that activate a function if the user set "active" and turn off the function, if the user set "Not active".

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom');
function custom() {
add_menu_page('settings', 'settings', '8', 'custom', 'customfunc');
}
function customfunc(){
$wpp_rg = get_option('wpp_rg');
if ($_POST['submit']):
update_option('wpp_rg',$_POST['wpp_rg']);
endif;
?>
<div class="wrap">
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
        <th scope="row">test mode :</th>
        <td><p>
         <label>
                <input name="wpp_rg" type="radio" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_0" <?php echo ($wpp_rg==1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '') ?> />
                active</label>
         <br />
         <label>
                <input name="wpp_rg" type="radio" value="2" id="RadioGroup1_1" <?php echo ($wpp_rg==2 ? 'checked="checked"' : '') ?>/>
                not active</label>
         <br />
        </p></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <th></th>
        <td><input type="submit" name="wpp_submit" value="save" class="button" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

$wpp_rg = get_option('wpp_rg');



/******************** IF1 ***********************/

if ($wpp_rg==1) {

echo "Active";



}
if ($wpp_rg==2) {

echo "Not Active";

}
/******************** IF1 ***********************/


?>
```

But the problem is that, the html radios are not working ! 
when i click "not active " and save, nothing happen !

What is the problem ? ?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be if($_POST['wpp_submit'])?

Comment: @gdaniel not work again :(

Comment: You really need to sanitize your input and use nonces, you're just asking to get hit by a cross site scripting attack.

Comment: You really need to be using the Settings API.

Comment: @vancoder That too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem could be with your add_menu_page() function.

You have your 3rd parameter set as '8' and that is a deprecated use of that particular parameter (capability). See:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

and

http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels

You should try changing that to the correct string representation.